# Returning TimeStamp multiple times in single T-SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a procedure returning the datetime of a particular timeZone .

```
CREATE Function [dbo].GetMyDate()  
Returns DATETIME  
As  
Begin  
 Return DateAdd(Hour,1,GetUTCDATE())  
End
```

If I call it two or three times in ONE T-SQL statement, will it give me the exactly same timestamp??
Or will it return different timestamps??

For eg,

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE GetMyDate() between GetMyDate() AND GetMyDate()
```

If I execute the above statement, will it ***always*** give "1" ??

Comment: I have already executed it locally, it exactly gives the same result.But, I'm wondering ,if it will give different result in some scenarios,something like executing in the table with so many records,etc..

Comment: @Kai - Your function will get executed every time. Considering SQL Server's `DateTime` only is accurate to [Rounded increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), you will get different results between calls. The reason you don't see them in your testscenario is because all calls return within the same time interval.

Comment: Thanks, Lieven. Can u let me know if  there are any articles that can prove it more?

Comment: @Kai - Not an article no but if you run following script, you can verify it yourself. `SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Var INTEGER = 1
WHILE @Var = 1 
BEGIN
  SELECT @Var = COUNT(*) WHERE dbo.GetMyDate() BETWEEN dbo.GetMyDate() AND dbo.GetMyDate()  
  SELECT @Var
END
`. It might take a while (13seconds here) but it will stop.

Comment: Thanks, Lieven. Now I get what I'm looking for. Can you post it as an answer , so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can you post it as an answer...*

**In short, no, it will not.**

The function in your testscenario gets executed three times.Now considering SQL Server's `DateTime` datatype ony being accurate to [Rounded increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), you **can** get different results between calls. The only reason you don't see them in your testscenario is because all calls return within the same time interval.

**Proof of concept**

Following script might take a while to execute but it will stop when the three seperate calls don't occur within the same interval.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @Var INTEGER = 1 
WHILE @Var = 1 
BEGIN 
  SELECT @Var = COUNT(*) 
  WHERE  dbo.GetMyDate() BETWEEN dbo.GetMyDate() AND dbo.GetMyDate()   

  SELECT @Var 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

As time progresses between calls to the function, is does not return the same `DateTime`, not even when used multiple times within the same statement, so:

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE GetMyDate() between GetMyDate() AND GetMyDate()
```

will not always return 1. Actually, there are many cases when it won't.

However, the following will:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = GetMyDate()

SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE @myDate BETWEEN @myDate AND @myDate
```

**EDIT**
On a side note: This would be more evident if SQL server handled times down to the millisecond. As it doesn't, there's chance that all three calls to the function are executed within the same millisecond-interval. In that case you get `1`. If SQL Server handled milliseconds, you'd never get `1` using the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

I have test your function on a long running query and i can tell you that it does not always return the same date and time. For every record the function is requestioned and returns a new date and time. Theoretically you can say that the difference in time is the same as the runtime of the query from the first to the last record. If your query runs for 3 seconds then the first row would return 9:34:48 (for example) and the last record 9:34:51. All the other records return theire own difference in seconds or milliseconds.

However, if the function is questioned multiple times in one row (like you're example) then the time returned seems to be the same. I think that's because the time it takes to run the query is too small to return a different time. If the function itself would take more time then it's still possible that it will return different times.

Answer (score 0):

This little program shows that the actual datetime differs. First, after 5 iterations,  milliseconds will differ. After apx. 14000-15000 iterations seconds will differ. Thus you will get different values depending on how much processing has been done between calls to your function.

```
declare @i  int 
set @i = 0
while (@i < 100000)
begin 
     set @i = @i + 1
     print convert(nvarchar(6), @i) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(50),dbo.GetMyDate(), 121)

end
```

Comment: The answer is as stated by others, It depends. It depends on how much processing is done in your query. No way to know that without testing it on *your* data doing real life queries. *Probably* you will be safe if your only calls to the function is in the same WHERE clause.

Comment: I think it would be safer to use Thorstens approach below. When in doubt it is better to play it safe.
To quote Dirty Harry: You've gotta ask yourself a question: "Do I feel lucky?"

Comment: Thanks, mortb. But , I think you get me wrong. I'm NOT looking for an solution, you can check my question. I'm just finding the proof that, in some scenario, it will give different result, even if it's executed in single query.

Comment: @Kai: Yes it is always a satisfaction in knowing what really happens.